# Get result like Excel Pivot Table in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to get a result like this.

[image]

And I have this table right now

[image]

Can anyone help me out?

I'd like to get this table by refreshing every day so I can keep up with the result.

Thanks in advance and any help will be warmly welcomed :D

Comment: It seems like I don't have enough credit to post images here, but the links are there! Hope you'll jump to the images and get what I meant to say!

Comment: Before even jumping this direction, please think twice - why do you really need this in BigQuery!? Usually this is a solid indication about not good design. Think what you really plan to do with it and share with us so we will be eable to help with better design.

Comment: Hi, Mikhail. First of all, thank you for your helpful advices.

Comment: What I was trying to do was get the pivoted table in red ash to share those KPIs.

Comment: As you may already noticed I’m pretty new to SQL and BigQuery field , so could you please tell me this is actually a bad design??

Comment: mainly because this is more visualization task. so in BigQuery you host and massage your data but then your use some tools to make visualizations. There are always exceptions of course and that is why you still can find many solutions here on SO related to pivoting. But, again, in  your case I think it is pure visualization

Comment: Hi. You're totally right. I was trying to visualize not only in Redash but even in BigQuery, too.

Answer (score 2):

While there are quite a number of pivot related posts on SO and good number of answers are provided by myself and other experts (so you might just need to search more on site), I wanted to share not-trivial option you have to do Excel style pivot right in BigQuery UI without any extra coding.
This can be useful when you have flattened data like in your example  - but you need quickly visualize it w/o leaving BigQuery UI

For this to work you need to use Chrome Extension [BigQuery Mate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bigquery-mate/nepgdloeceldecnoaaegljlichnfognh) (*as you can see from my profile I am an author/developer of it*)

So, when you have it installed - follow below steps

1. Make sure you select needed data into result panel as below (i just generate random values to mimic your scenario)

[image]

2. Expand Result Panel by clicking on green <kbd>+</kbd> button - now you can see up to 500 rows

[image]

3. Click green <kbd>Show Pivot</kbd> button to generate Graph / Pivot from those visible (up to 500) rows of data

[image]

4. Finally, set / tune your pivot / graph as per your needs / preferences - for example as below

[image]

5. To go back to normal UI state  - click on <kbd>Hide Pivot</kbd> and then <kbd>--</kbd> button

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll try this out immediately!

Comment: did you have chance to try?